# CSS Counters for page footer not incrementing in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I tried to implement a page numeration on a printed document.
So I tried to do it by using counters. But, with the following implementation, the counter is not incrementing for every page.

```css
    /* Réglages par défaut pour l'écran */
#en-tete-impression,
#pied-de-page-impression {
  display: none;
}

/* Uniquement pour l'impression */
@media print {

  body {
      counter-reset: page;
  }

  h1 {
    page-break-before: always;
    padding-top: 2em;
    }

  h1:first-child {
    page-break-before: avoid;
    counter-reset: page;
    }

  #en-tete-impression {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0pt;
    left:0pt;
    right: 0pt;

    font-size: 200%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #pied-de-page-impression {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0pt;
    right: 0pt;

    font-size: 200%;
  }

  #pied-de-page-impression:after {
    content: counter(page);
    counter-increment: page;
  }

} /* fin des paramètres pour l'impression */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Exemple à imprimer</title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Section A</h1>
    <p>Ceci est la première section...</p>

    <h1>Section B</h1>
    <p>Ceci est la seconde section...</p>

    <div id="en-tete-impression">
      Titre pour les médias paginés
    </div>

    <div id="pied-de-page-impression">
      Page : 
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

The footer is present but the page number doesn't increment at every page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like it's a bug in Chromium engine: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=774830

Answer (score 0):

Chrome will refuse to increment the counter until you call the counter reset. Once you will do that, whole thing started working. this code might work for you

```
body {
    counter-reset: page;
}
footer {
    counter-increment: page;
}
#footer-content {
    content: counter(page);
}
```

Comment: I tried to add the 'counter-reset: page;' but the counter incrementation still does'nt work